# Cannot validate a non-balanced entry error on validate supplier invoice OpenERP 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-view

I have faced the warning pop on validate the supplier invoice with OpenERP 7

```
1 - select supplier invoice and select supplier
2 - Add Product in invoice line
3 - select Other Info Tab and Add Payment Terms
4 - Validate the invoice
```

When trying to validate an invoice the application issues an error below OpenERP Warning :

**"You cannot validate a non-balanced entry.
   Make sure you have configured payment terms properly.
   The latest payment term line should be of the "Balance" type."**

Warning message raise only when there are debit and credit balance will not be matched.

I am also follwing the below article

https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/506521

Our customer using the old base addons for accouting related module in OpenERP V7
Also apply so many other patch on my existing addons for openerp V7

but not finding any solution relavent with this issue

Any one have idea what are the stapes need to stop my warning popup . or  Is there any preconfiguration needed to solve my issue

Comment: Hello Dasadiya,

At time of Invoice payment, If related journal entries are unbalanced then system will give us this kind of error, so here, If you can provide us your Invoice configuration then we can help us. 

One Solution is available, If you can ticked of that related Invoice Account as "Centralized Counterpart" then you can move ahead on that Invoice, but then related journal entries will be unbalanced there.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I had fixed it from my end. I found the issue into the conflict another customize module method. thanks for the update